# How to access the methods of an object inside another object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program that consists of a 'master' object, which keeps track of and manipulates many smaller objects. Here is a simplified example:

```
class My_obj:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def set_a(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

class Master:

    def __init__(self, list_):
        self.obj_list = []
        for value in list_:
            obj = My_obj(value)
            self.obj_list.append(obj)

m = Master([0, 1, 2])

# How do I get (or set) the value of <a> from one of the My_obj instances
# within the new Master object?
```

I know of two ways to do this. The first is to add a method to `Master` that returns the requested object:

```
    def get_obj(self, index):
        return self.obj_list[index]
```

I could then call any method directly on the object. However, this seems dangerous: if subsequent code deletes the returned object, and then something in `Master` tries to look it up, the program would crash.

**EDIT**:
Turns out it would not crash, but still a problem; see comments.

The second way would be to wrap each method with a corresponding method in `Master`:

```
    def set_a(self, index, a):
        self.obj_list[index].set_a(a)

    def get_a(self, index):
        return self.obj_list[index].get_a()
```

This seems redundant, and would get quite tedious in a more complicated scenario.

Does anyone know of a better way to access these methods?

Comment: "what if subsequent code deletes the returned object, and then something in Master tries to look it up?"  That can't really happen. The Master object will still have a reference to the returned object, so it won't get deleted.

Comment: Do it the easy way and if you have a problem, refactor it later.

Comment: You have already provided 2 ways yourself. I guess you just want a "safe" way to do it? Why do you feel the second way is redundant? It is not very verbose imo..

Comment: @matt, can the subsequent code not modify the returned object in some way though?

Comment: you can also set via the master object directly, `master_obj.obj_list[index].a = "some new value"`

Comment: @monkut: it was my understanding that accessing object attributes directly was frowned upon. Am I mistaken?

Comment: It depends on your use case.  It's hard to know what to suggest without knowing how your objects are going to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print m.obj_list[0].get_a() # prints 0
m.obj_list[0].set_a(5)
print m.obj_list[0].get_a() # prints 5
# access all the "a"'s
a_s = [o.get_a() for o in m.obj_list]
```

Comment: Is it 'proper' to access object attributes directly like that? I was under the impression that that should be used mainly for debugging, and that the real code should use methods exclusively. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Define 'proper'... I guess that the answer depends on what you're trying to do - which is a bit difficult to understand from this example. If you want encapsulation (hide the data-structure but expose the data) then you should create the "redundant" access methods in `Master` while if all you want is a nested data-structure you should do it without using classes and objects